# Terminate particular Flux stream on the server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I'm trying to build a simple chat server using Spring WebFlux. It's easy stuff and working as excepted. What i'm trying to implement now is a termination of the Flux stream on the server side. Imagine a have an infinite Flux exposed like this:

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Object> join(@PathVariable String user)
```

and  i have 10 clients/subscribers connected to that event stream. Now i'd like to terminate connection of one particular client because e.g. user cursed on the chat. Whatever. Is it possible to manage/identify subscribers of such endpoint?

Comment: I do have the same question, Have you got the answer yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could  build something utilizing the [`.takeUntilOther(Publisher)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntilOther-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) operator, and have the given `Publisher` emit when the user should be disconnected...

```java
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Object> join(@PathVariable String user) {
    return Flux.from(/* your logic to build your flux */)
               .takeUntilOther(disconnector.onDisconnectUser(user));
}
```

One possible implementation for `onDisconnectUser(String user)` would be to filter a "global" hot `Flux<String>` that emits usernames to disconnect by the given username.  Perhaps something like this:

```java
public class UserDisconnecter {

    private final FluxProcessor<String, String> processor;
    private final FluxSink<String> sink;

    public UserDisconnecter() {
        this.processor = DirectProcessor.create();
        this.sink = this.processor.sink();
    }

    /**
     * Signals that all existing streams for this user should be disconnected.
     */
    public void disconnectUser(String user) {
        this.sink.next(user);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Mono that emits when the given user should be disconnected.
     */
    public Mono<String> onDisconnectUser(String user) {
        return processor
            .filter(user::equals)
            .next();
    }
}
```

This is a simplistic implementation, but should be something to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Very elegant approach. I accept your solution.